# Access NSImage from Assets programmatically with IBDesignable

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, interface-builder

The regular loading via `NSImage(named: "image_name")` crashes the IBDesignable renderer as it apparently runs in a separate bundle.

In iOS there is a workaround to load images passing in the bundle explicitly:

`let bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name", in: bundle, compatibleWith: self.traitCollection)!`

In Cocoa the analog initializer is missing.

Is there any other way to load the images from the Assets catalog?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Swift 3 or higher, you can try image literals. It should auto-complete in Xcode so if it doesn't work it might indicate a problem with the asset itself. Using a UIButton for example:

```
let myButton = UIButton()
myButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "image_name"), for: .normal)
```

By typing `Image Literal` Xcode should auto-complete it and create a small icon which you can double-click to open an image picker and select the image you want to use. A more complete guide on image literals and literals in general can be found [here](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/be-literal-76e9b4389eda)

Comment: I tried image literals as well but they seem to come from the main bundle so it crashes the IBDesignable renderer as well.